# Why does having too many principal components for handwritten digits classification result in less accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pca

I'm currently using PCA to do handwritten digits recognition for MNIST database (each digit has about 1000 observations and 784 features). One thing I have found confusing is that the accuracy is the highest when it has 40 PCs. If the number of PCs grows from this point, the accuracy starts to drop continuously.

From my understanding of PCA, I thought the more components I have, the better I can describe a dataset. Why does the accuracy becomes less if I have too many PCs?

Answer (score 0):

- In order to identify the optimum number of components, you need to plot the `elbow curve`
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)
- The idea behind PCA is to reduce the dimensionality of the data by finding the principal components.

Lastly, I do not think that PCA can overfit the data as it is not a learning/ fitting algorithm.

You are just trying to project the data based on eigen-vectors to capture most of the variance along an axis.

This video should help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UVHneBUBW0